# Android store imageview to sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

AddNote.java---in Onclick(View v){}

```
            String name = et_Notename.getText().toString();
            String description = et_Notedescription.getText().toString();
            dbconnection.insertNote(name, description);
            Intent main = new Intent(AddNote.this, NoteActivity.class)
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(main);
```

AddNote.java---in onSelected(intent data){}

```
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
            ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageData = baos.toByteArray();
```

DBhelperNote.java---create database

```
            private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTE + " (" +
            NOTE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            NOTE_NAME + " text not null, " +
            NOTE_DESCRIPTION + " text not null, "+
            NOTE_PHOTO + " blob not null "+
            " );";
```

SQLControler.java---in insertNote(String name,String description,String photo){}

```
            public void insertNote(String name,String description,String photo) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(DBhelperNote.NOTE_NAME, name);
            cv.put(DBhelperNote.NOTE_DESCRIPTION, description);
            cv.put(DBhelperNote.NOTE_PHOTO, photo );
            database.insert(DBhelperNote.TABLE_NOTE, null, cv);
            }
```

How do i insert my imageData to sqlite database that i already created ?

Comment: For a blob, use a byte array.

Comment: still can't figure it out